# undefined reference to 'cvUndistortPoints' in opencv4android

Tags: android, opencv

I was working on the mobile project with opencv4android (NDK) library.
The code works fine with the version 2.3.1.
After I updated the library to the version 2.4.2, I met some unexpected errors which caused by this line:

```
projectPoints( (cv::Mat)obj_cube, rvec, tvec, K, Z, scene_cube );
```

**The error info:**

```
jni/libs/libopencv_calib3d.a(calibration.cpp.o): In function `icvGetRectangles(CvMat const*, CvMat const*, CvMat const*, CvMat const*, CvSize, cv::Rect_<float>&, cv::Rect_<float>&)':
calibration.cpp:(.text._ZL16icvGetRectanglesPK5CvMatS1_S1_S1_6CvSizeRN2cv5Rect_IfEES6_+0x11c): undefined reference to `cvUndistortPoints'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/Users/huidong/Documents/workspace/com.qualcomm.fastcorner.SplashScreen'
jni/libs/libopencv_calib3d.a(calibration.cpp.o): In function `cvStereoRectify':
calibration.cpp:(.text.cvStereoRectify+0x59e): undefined reference to `cvUndistortPoints'
jni/libs/libopencv_calib3d.a(calibration.cpp.o): In function `cv::rectify3Collinear(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::Size_<int>, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, double, cv::Size_<int>, cv::Rect_<int>*, cv::Rect_<int>*, int)':
calibration.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv17rectify3CollinearERKNS_11_InputArrayES2_S2_S2_S2_S2_S2_S2_NS_5Size_IiEES2_S2_S2_S2_RKNS_12_OutputArrayES7_S7_S7_S7_S7_S7_dS4_PNS_5Rect_IiEESA_i+0xda2): undefined reference to `cv::undistortPoints(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
calibration.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv17rectify3CollinearERKNS_11_InputArrayES2_S2_S2_S2_S2_S2_S2_NS_5Size_IiEES2_S2_S2_S2_RKNS_12_OutputArrayES7_S7_S7_S7_S7_S7_dS4_PNS_5Rect_IiEESA_i+0xe2a): undefined reference to `cv::undistortPoints(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
jni/libs/libopencv_calib3d.a(calibration.cpp.o): In function `cvFindExtrinsicCameraParams2':
calibration.cpp:(.text.cvFindExtrinsicCameraParams2+0x89e): undefined reference to `cvUndistortPoints'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libfastcvsample.so] Error 1
make: [all] Error 2
```

**The main problem is:**

```
calibration.cpp: undefined reference to 'cvUndistortPoints'
```

If I comment the projectPoints function, the error will disappear. I have added all the opencv libraries.
Did I still miss something or some bugs in the new version?

Answer (score 0):

The method signature for `cvUndistortPoints` is missing. The update definitely broke your dependencies.

There might be multiple reasons:

- the method got renamed (unlikely)
- the method signature changed (likely) to add new functionality (in this case you'll need to wait for another update, since the method is being references from another method)
- the shared library which contains the method got moved (likely) and you're linking against libraries which do not contain the method (are you really adding all libraries ?)

Check if the method signature:

```
 cv::undistortPoints(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&)
```

still exists by looking at the reference documentation (in your update's archive/doc) or by peeking at the library which is supposed to contain it (on unix for example by using the `nm` tool on a potential candidate library):

```
cd /PATH_TO_YOUR_OPENCV_LIBS_INSTALL
nm libopencv_calib3d.so (find out which library is supposed to have the signature)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It seems like opencv4android 2.4.2 changed a lot on the APIs as well as the organization of the library. More errors appeared later, so I directly changed the version back to 2.3.1, and everything works fine~

Comment: You're welcome. This reminds me of pre opencv 1.0 days with ffmpeg pre0.4.9, where every tweak to the video libraries broke some dependencies in the upper layer libraries. The problem with OpenCV is still that too many people are using it and too few are contributing to the code-base :)